# CSS counter up @property in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, counter, mobile-safari

My counter up css code doesn't work on Safari (mobile: 12.4.9, desktop: Mojave). I am trying hard **NOT TO USE** javascript. Can you help?

My code

```css
@property --num{syntax:"<integer>";initial-value:300;inherits:false}
.c300{animation:counter 29s ease-in-out;counter-reset:num var(--num)}
.c300::after{content:counter(num)}
@keyframes counter{from{--num:0}to{--num:300} }
```

```html
<div>
<h3 class="c300"></h3>
<p>total</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Safari doesn't support `@property`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property

Comment: You are correct. I have also send an issue to the website because Opera Android supports @property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is an experimental technology. Not yet supported by Firefox and Safari.